# Service worker unable to control client

Tags: reactjs, firebase, service-worker

The resources on internet on this topic are very ambiguous and cannot be used until I get a complete documentation on this.

I have below service worker in react that receives firebase push notification inside `setBackgroundMessageHandler` function:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.24.0/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "****",
    databaseURL: "https://gratis-3ce5a.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "gratis-3ce5a",
    storageBucket: "gratis-3ce5a.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "G-PNXHN4YXYF"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

  const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.data.body,
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

 self.clients.matchAll({
    includeUncontrolled: 'true'
  }).then(function(clients){
    clients[0].postMessage({data: notificationTitle});
  })
});
```

Below is my component in which I want to receive message:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import {  onMessageListener } from './firebaseInit';

export const Messaging=()=>{
    const [message, setMessage]=useState('');
    navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log(event.data);
    };
    
    return(
        <h1>{message}</h1>
    );
}
```

Below is the `serviceWorker.js` file:

```
export const registerServiceWorker = () => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('firebase-messaging-sw.js')
      .then(function (registration) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('[SW]: SCOPE: ', registration.scope);
        return registration.scope;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        return err;
      });
  }
};
```

I am successfully receiving message in `setBackgroundMessageHandler`, but the message is not reaching the functional react component.

This is my first time with service workers. I have no idea how they communicate with react components. Please help me to find problems in my code and correct it.

**EDIT**
I have gone to the root of the problem and have noticed that the service worker is unable to control the client. Although I have been successfull in posting message to the client, but would still want to know the reason behind service worker not controlling the client.

Comment: Actually this is the most random try by me. What I'm actually trying to do is to send data from service worker to react component. I have checked almost all resources on this, but none of them is working.

Comment: I am very surprised to see thus question not receiving any response.